# Добавление курса валют

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поставить на сайт информацию ЦБ Армении - курсы валют?

Answer (score 3):

1. Формируете запрос вида:
   `http://api.cba.am/ExchangeRatesToCSV.ashx?DateFrom=2012-01-01&DateTo=2012-03-30&ISOCodes=USD,GBP,RUB,EUR`
       подставляя нужные даты и коды валют, при этом даты задаются в формате yyyy-mm-dd
2. Разбираете полученный CSV. Поля данных разделяются запятой. Первая строка - заголовок, каждая последующая представляет собой значения курсов за конкретную дату, при этом первое поле (дата) задается в формате dd/mm/yyyy, после последнего поля также следует запятая. Например, первые три строки для приведенного выше запроса выглядят так:
   `Ամսաթիվ,USD,GBP,RUB,EUR`
   `09/01/2012,386.1500,596.2200,12.1200,493.2700,`
   `10/01/2012,387.0700,599.3800,12.2000,495.1800,`

Answer (score 1):

Дальше, надеюсь, справитесь сами, потому что я не знаю Вашего проекта и Ваших конкретных целей.

```
$data=file_get_contents('http://www.cba.am/am/SitePages/Default.aspx');
preg_match_all('/<b>USD<\/b>.*?<\/li>\r/i', $data, $arr);
echo htmlspecialchars($arr[0][0]);
```

Результат

```
<b>USD</b></em><em class="w_50">1</em><em class="w_50">390.64</em><em class="w_40 ico_green">0.34</em><div class="ac clear"></div></li><li class="light_gray_2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ddw1="http://www.cba.am/" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal"><em class="w_50"><b>GBP</b></em><em class="w_50">1</em><em class="w_50">625.45</em><em class="w_40 ico_green">4.99</em><div class="ac clear"></div></li><li class="light_gray_2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ddw1="http://www.cba.am/" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal"><em class="w_50"><b>EUR</b></em><em class="w_50">1</em><em class="w_50">521.39</em><em class="w_40 ico_green">3.07</em><div class="ac clear"></div></li><li class="light_gray_2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ddw1="http://www.cba.am/" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal"><em class="w_50"><b>RUB</b></em><em class="w_50">1</em><em class="w_50">13.31</em><em class="w_40 ico_green">0.03</em><div class="ac clear"></div></li>
```